# Width of element is fractional number in FF and IE but integer in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with cross-browser HTML makeup. In Firefox and Internet Explorer the width of a div container made with bootstrap is a fractional number (900.5 for example), and the child element fully inherits this width. In Chrome the container still has a fractional width (900.5), but the width of the child element is an integer (900), and I'd like to keep it that way. The question is, how am I supposed to do this without hardcoding the width?

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-9 nopadding" style="left: -1px;">
                 <div id="content">                      //this divs width is 900.5 everywhere
                     <div id="content-table"></div>      //this divs width is 900 in Chrome and 900.5 in FF and IE
                 </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to upload the whole problem in jsFiddle because media queries do not work correctly there, so I put the code with almost the same situation [here](http://pastebin.com/XL6mbTDR). In the example you can also see that element with `id="content"` has fractional width everywhere, but his child with `id="content-table"` has integer width in Chrome and fractional in FF and IE.

Comment: Does it also render differently?

Comment: Yes it does, Gust van de Wal. It affects pagination very bad, and has to be fixed ;(

Comment: Could you turn it into a Fiddle, so we can try and solve it ourselves?

Comment: Yes I can, but I'll have to remove many things first, so it will take the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to change the `display` property of the `#content-table` element. You used `display:table`, that let the element behave like a `<table>` element. In your case it is not needed because you don't use any `table-cell`, `table-row`, etc. child element (like `display:table-cell` or `display:table-row`).

You can simply use `display:block`. In this case the child element will be fractional in Chrome too. In your example will appear a scroll-bar, but you can use `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden` to hide it.
I created a JSFiddle example for the solution, using `width: 200.5px` for the `#content` element, but it is working in your code too. The link for the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jeqmefxy/